# Regex how to match "not \1"

Tags: regex

for example:
if i match "1+2+1" use "`/[0-9](\+|\-)[0-9](\1)[0-9]`",it works,

but now i want to match  "1+2-1",
but the regex "`/[0-9](\+|\-)[0-9][^(\1)][0-9]/`" didn't work.

so how to match the "NOT \1"?

Comment: Can you explain that further? What do you mean by "the NOT \1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use negative lookahead and don't match it if it's the same as first matched char. You can fiddle around with this expression; `[0-9]([+-])[0-9](?:(?!\1)[+-])[0-9]`

https://regex101.com/r/mSSSlJ/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to match both of the text:

```
[0-9](\+|\-)[0-9](\1)*[+-][0-9]
```